# Script to remove shortcuts won't work with version numbers

Tags: vbscript

I'm running a vbscript to remove desktop shortcuts installed by another program, the problem I have though is one shortcut is being stubborn

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop" )
' delete this shortcut
strShortcut = strDesktop & "\Shortcut Name 2.0.lnk"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(strShortcut) Then fso.DeleteFile(strShortcut)
```

I have a feeling it's to do with the version number and decimal point in-between? Can anyone confirm my suspicion as I'm completely out of clues.

Thanks.

Comment: It should work either way. Can you describe what "doesn't work" mean? It's not deleted? If this is the case, can you check which part fails, the detection or deletion? And please double-check there there aren't other discrepancies, such as maybe two spaces instead of one inside the filename

Comment: @CherryDT sorry, yes the shortcut is not deleted. I duplicated the shortcut without the ".0" on the end of the name version and it works fine, so I can only presume there's a confliction with the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you want to delete probably doesn't already exist, `If fso.FileExists(strShortcut) Then` masks that fact.

A shortcut you see in your desktop doesn't have to be in your `Desktop` folder that you acquired with `WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")`.

There is another location where desktop items are stored as an extension to the all users' desktop directories, but may require administrative privileges to modify, I'm not sure, you need to try.

So, in addition to `SpecialFolders("Desktop")`, you should also consider the `SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")` directory.

```vb
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

userDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
publicDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")

shortcutName = "Shortcut Name 2.0.lnk"

userShortcut = Fso.BuildPath(userDesktop, shortcutName)
publicShortcut = Fso.BuildPath(publicDesktop, shortcutName)

If Fso.FileExists(userShortcut) Then 
    Fso.DeleteFile userShortcut, True
    MsgBox "User shortcut deleted."
End If

If Fso.FileExists(publicShortcut) Then
    Fso.DeleteFile publicShortcut, True
    MsgBox "Public shortcut deleted."
End If
```